# Inconsistent behaviour in Realm write

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I am having trouble with a write operation in Realm. All other read/writes are working perfectly as expected apart from this one and I am stumped as to what may be causing this issue.

I have a game object in realm and it has an array which holds score type of objects. When the user joins a game, the API responds with an array of placeholder score objects. I am trying to add these scores to the game object. Based on different flows the game object may or may not have yet been written to `Realm`. I am using the following code to add scores to the game object. `Game` and `Scores` here are subclasses of `RLMObject`

```
[[RLMRealm defaultRealm] transactionWithBlock:^{
    RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
    //NSArray *scores contains all score objects to be added
    Game game = [Game createOrUpdateInRealm:realm withValue:aGame];

    for (Score *aScore in scores) {
        Score *rlmScore = [Score createOrUpdateInRealm:realm withValue:aScore];
        [game.scores addObject:rlmScore];
    }

    //Pass game to next ViewController for display
}];
```

The problem is that by the end of this transaction block the game.scores array has 1 score object even though the loop has run more than once since the scores array has more than 1 object. Even weirded is the fact that this problem does not always happen. No other operation is going on in another thread. The UI is blocked and waiting for the API response at this point and only continues after this write transaction.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Logging [game.scores valueForKey:@"scoreID"] inside the loop after addObject: call logs the last score ID that was added, suggesting that the RLMArray game.scores is somehow either being re-initialised each iteration or its overwriting the first object each iteration.

Comment: what is `scores`? Is it from Realm?

Comment: scores is an NSArray <Score*>. While Score is an RLMObject, scores has been created in memory and is not fetched from Realm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[[RLMRealm defaultRealm] transactionWithBlock:^{
    RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
    //NSArray *scores contains all score objects to be added
    Game game = [Game createOrUpdateInRealm:realm withValue:aGame];

    NSMutableArray *rlmScores = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (Score *aScore in scores) {
        Score *rlmScore = [Score createOrUpdateInRealm:realm withValue:aScore];
        [rlmScores addObject:rlmScore];
    }

    [game.scores addObjects:rlmScores];

    //Pass game to next ViewController for display
}];
```

Adding the Realm score objects to an array and then adding the array to game.scores RLMArray worked. I have no idea why this worked and adding the objects one by one in a loop won't work. I am posting the solution that worked for me if anyone else runs into a similar problem.

Please feel free to provide a better solution or an explanation for the issue.